# The Legendre Transform of Bernoulli r.v.s

Tags: probability-theory, transformation

This question is most likely related to calculus/algebra and tricks regarding supremums rather than actual understanding of large deviations and the Legendre transform, but anyway. For a random variable $X_1$, we define a convex function

$$
H(\alpha) = \log M(\alpha),
$$

where $M(\alpha) = E^{\alpha X_1}$ is the moment generating function for $X_1$. Let $L$ be the Legendre transform of $H(\alpha)$, i.e.

$$
L(\beta) = \sup_{\alpha} [\alpha \beta - H(\alpha)].
$$

As an example of $H(\alpha)$ and $L(\beta)$, suppose that $X_1$ is Bernoulli with $P(X_1 = 0) = 1 - p, P(X_1 = 1) = p$ for $p \in (0, 1)$. Then $H(\alpha) = \log((1 - p) + pe^{\alpha})$ and

$$
L(\beta) = \begin{cases} \beta \log(\frac{\beta}{p}) + (1 - \beta) \log(\frac{1 - \beta}{1 - p}) & \beta \in [0, 1] \\ \infty & \beta \notin [0, 1] \end{cases}.
$$

My question is: while I understand how we got $H(\alpha)$ quite easily, I cannot figure out at all how we arrived at $L(\beta)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that the function $\alpha\mapsto\alpha\beta-H(\alpha)$ is maximal when the derivative $\beta-H'(\alpha)$ is zero. This allows to deduce an expression of the optimal $\alpha$, say $\alpha_\beta$, in terms of $\beta$ and to compute $L(\beta)$ as $L(\beta)=\alpha_\beta\beta-H(\alpha_\beta)$. If that derivative is never $0$, one considers the limit as $\alpha\to\pm\infty$.

Comment: ... and if that derivative is never $0$, you consider the limit as $\alpha \to +\infty$ or $-\infty$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Right. May I insert this in my answer?

Comment: of course you may, why not?

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. One more question: so I got $\alpha_\beta = \log(\frac{\beta(1 - p)}{p(1 - \beta)})$. How do I calculate $H(\alpha_\beta) = -\log E(\frac{\beta (1 - p)}{p (1 - \beta)})^X = \log E(\frac{p (1 - \beta)}{\beta (1 - p)})^X$? Based on the statement that should give $\log(\frac{1 - \beta}{1 - p})$ for $\beta \in [0, 1]$, but I don't know how to calculate that.

Comment: This is strange, you know $H(\alpha)$ for every $\alpha$ hence you can plug directly the value of $\alpha_\beta$ in this expression rather than going back to the computation of $H$.